# mongoose | find query with timeout

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to run a find query with timeout, but the timeout doesn't seems to have any impact.

```
myModel.find(query, select, {maxTimeMS: 1000, skip:0, limit: 1000}).lean().exec(function(){...}
```

I've using mongoose version 5.0.12

What am I missing?

Duplicate attempt:

```
myModel.find(query, select, {skip:0, limit: 1000}).maxTime(1000).lean().exec(function(){...}
```

Comment: the answer in the duplicated question doesn't work

Comment: It still works fine when I try it with Mongoose 5.1.1. Can you update your question to show how you're trying to use the answer in the linked dupe?

Comment: Hi, i've added the new attempt to the original question

Comment: Well, it should be `lean()`, but what else isn't working about it?

Comment: it's lean() - just forgot to add the `()` in the question.
i'm not receiving a timeout for a request that takes about 5 seconds

Comment: Thanks, your code works fine for me when I try it, giving an ExceededTimeLimit error if I set the maxTime value low enough.

Comment: strange... i'm not getting timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/aheckmann/mquery#maxtime

```
myModel.find(query, select).maxTime(1000).exec(function(err, doc) { ... });
```

Also you can test it inside console.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/

Comment: i actually have more flags under OPTIONS. i've updated my question